# jQuery hide cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm currently trying to figure out how to make a jQuery toggle button which hides a banner on my website remember if it has been hidden with a simple cookie. Perhaps jQuery cookie?

The code is incredibly simple however I have never coded any cookies in my life and javascript isn't my expertise.

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$(".adultbanner").hide(1000);
});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="adultbanner">
<div class="adultwrap">
<h1><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></h1>
<h2>You must be at least 18 years of age to use this website. To find out more information click <a href="#">here...</a></h2>
<button>Hide</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with google?

Comment: @A.Wolff Trust me, I've googled this to DEATH

Comment: You could use localStorage: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: @JobyKent You are lying, you aren't dead... ;) See e.g localstorage: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-local-storage-for-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest and best supported solution would be to use http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

```
$.cookie('bannerHidden', true, { expires: 7 });
```

The last parameter makes the cookie expire in a week, or you can simply omit that to have the cookie kept indefinitely.

Comment: How can I attach the name 'bannerHidden' to my javascript function so it will work? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use localstorage if you are using html5 to store information.